# FTP client receives whole file, but always closes connection before finishing

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard machine, I'm having trouble connecting to and downloading a file from a Windows FTP server.

Filesize is ~3KB to 6KB.  Very rarely ~100KB to ~500KB, but the server has plenty of space on disk.

I've tried a passive connection:

```
Response:   220-Microsoft FTP Service
Response:   220 Regal Logistics
Command:    USER ********
Response:   331 Password required for ********.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 User ******** logged in.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting download of /********/PO/201405130227.xml
Command:    CWD /********/PO
Response:   250 CWD command successful.
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Type set to A.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,**,19,64)
Command:    RETR 201405130227.xml
Response:   125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
Response:   426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 3,465 bytes in 1 second
```

The strange thing is that the file is 3,465 bytes, so the entire file is getting through, it just isn't finishing up properly.

And I've tried an active connection:

```
Response:   220-Microsoft FTP Service
Response:   220 Regal Logistics
Command:    USER ********
Response:   331 Password required for ********.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 User ******** logged in.
Command:    PORT 10,0,0,114,214,65
Response:   200 PORT command successful.
Command:    RETR 201405130227.xml
Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for 201405130227.xml(3465 bytes).
Response:   426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content
```

I've tried from two different FTP clients on the same server (Filezilla and the CLI FTP client) and I get the same response:

```
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content
```

I've attempted downloading files successfully from a separate network, so it's unique to the server's location.

I've contacted both the system/network administrators of where the server is located and I've been assured that the ports necessary for FTP to function are open.  (My guess is that they've opened 21, I'm not sure about any others.)  There is a physical firewall that is on their network, but again, I don't have access to it unfortunately.  Windows Firewall is disabled on the server.

What else could I take a look at to see if it's truly failing?

Here's a packet log of the request just before failing:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination                Protocol  Length Info
     39 6.878855000    LOCAL-IP            EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP        FTP      77     Request: RETR 201405130227.xml

Frame 39: 77 bytes on wire (616 bits), 77 bytes captured (616 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_ab:cd:ef (00:1e:a1:ab:cd:ef), Dst: Watchgua_12:34:56 (ab:cd:7f:12:34:56)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: LOCAL-IP (LOCAL-IP), Dst: EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP (EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 56623 (56623), Dst Port: ftp (21), Seq: 55, Ack: 207, Len: 23
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

No.     Time           Source                Destination                Protocol  Length Info
     40 6.893662000    EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP        LOCAL-IP            TCP      60     ftp > 56623 [ACK] Seq=207 Ack=78 Win=93362 Len=0

Frame 40: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_12:34:56 (ab:cd:7f:12:34:56), Dst: Hewlett-_ab:cd:ef (00:1e:a1:ab:cd:ef)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP (EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP), Dst: LOCAL-IP (LOCAL-IP)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 56623 (56623), Seq: 207, Ack: 78, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination                Protocol  Length Info
     41 6.957666000    EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP        LOCAL-IP            FTP      108    Response: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

Frame 41: 108 bytes on wire (864 bits), 108 bytes captured (864 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_12:34:56 (ab:cd:7f:12:34:56), Dst: Hewlett-_ab:cd:ef (00:1e:a1:ab:cd:ef)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP (EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP), Dst: LOCAL-IP (LOCAL-IP)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 56623 (56623), Seq: 207, Ack: 78, Len: 54
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

No.     Time           Source                Destination                Protocol  Length Info
     42 6.986757000    EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP        LOCAL-IP            FTP      106    Response: 426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content

Frame 42: 106 bytes on wire (848 bits), 106 bytes captured (848 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_12:34:56 (ab:cd:7f:12:34:56), Dst: Hewlett-_ab:cd:ef (00:1e:a1:ab:cd:ef)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP (EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP), Dst: LOCAL-IP (LOCAL-IP)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 56623 (56623), Seq: 261, Ack: 78, Len: 52
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

No.     Time           Source                Destination                Protocol  Length Info
     43 6.986768000    LOCAL-IP            EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP        TCP      54     56623 > ftp [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=313 Win=65280 Len=0

Frame 43: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_ab:cd:ef (00:1e:a1:ab:cd:ef), Dst: Watchgua_12:34:56 (ab:cd:7f:12:34:56)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: LOCAL-IP (LOCAL-IP), Dst: EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP (EXTERNAL-FTP-SERVER-IP)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 56623 (56623), Dst Port: ftp (21), Seq: 78, Ack: 313, Len: 0
```

---

I collected a few more logs - this time I watched more than ports 21 and 22 - I watched the IPs of the FTP connection:

```
    No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2607 11.440148000   __REMOTE__IP__        _LOCAL_IP_            FTP      105    Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (198,104,198,16,17,233)

Frame 2607: 105 bytes on wire (840 bits), 105 bytes captured (840 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC), Dst: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__), Dst: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 54613 (54613), Seq: 195, Ack: 60, Len: 51
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2608 11.440763000   _LOCAL_IP_            __REMOTE__IP__        FTP      74     Request: RETR testthing.txt

Frame 2608: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC), Dst: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_), Dst: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54613 (54613), Dst Port: ftp (21), Seq: 60, Ack: 246, Len: 20
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2609 11.441029000   _LOCAL_IP_            __REMOTE__IP__        TCP      66     54617 > 4585 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=128 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 2609: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC), Dst: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_), Dst: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54617 (54617), Dst Port: 4585 (4585), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2610 11.442013000   __REMOTE__IP__        _LOCAL_IP_            TCP      60     ftp > 54613 [ACK] Seq=246 Ack=80 Win=93360 Len=0

Frame 2610: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC), Dst: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__), Dst: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 54613 (54613), Seq: 246, Ack: 80, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2622 11.459434000   __REMOTE__IP__        _LOCAL_IP_            TCP      66     4585 > 54617 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 WS=2 MSS=1400 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 2622: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC), Dst: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__), Dst: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4585 (4585), Dst Port: 54617 (54617), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2623 11.459475000   _LOCAL_IP_            __REMOTE__IP__        TCP      54     54617 > 4585 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=4194304 Len=0

Frame 2623: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC), Dst: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_), Dst: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54617 (54617), Dst Port: 4585 (4585), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2634 11.482207000   __REMOTE__IP__        _LOCAL_IP_            FTP      108    Response: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

Frame 2634: 108 bytes on wire (864 bits), 108 bytes captured (864 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC), Dst: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__), Dst: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 54613 (54613), Seq: 246, Ack: 80, Len: 54
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2635 11.483996000   __REMOTE__IP__        _LOCAL_IP_            FTP-DATA 60     FTP Data: 4 bytes

Frame 2635: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC), Dst: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__), Dst: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4585 (4585), Dst Port: 54617 (54617), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 4
FTP Data (test)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2636 11.484173000   __REMOTE__IP__        _LOCAL_IP_            FTP      106    Response: 426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content

Frame 2636: 106 bytes on wire (848 bits), 106 bytes captured (848 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Watchgua_LOCALMAC (AA:BB:CC:LOCALMAC), Dst: Hewlett-_SUB_MAC (11:22:33:SUB_MAC)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: __REMOTE__IP__ (__REMOTE__IP__), Dst: _LOCAL_IP_ (_LOCAL_IP_)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ftp (21), Dst Port: 54613 (54613), Seq: 300, Ack: 80, Len: 52
File Transfer Protocol (FTP)
```

---

Ah - so we tested connecting to an FTP server that used a nonstandard control port and the file transfer worked correctly.

Only when we connect to an FTP server that uses the standard control port of 21 does the transfer have problems.

---

We cleared the firewall's settings, rebuilt, and reset the settings on the firewall.  The issue was then fixed.

The settings that were applied were identical to the settings that existed before.  The settings on the firewall somehow became corrupt.  That's all she wrote, really.

Comment: You could try switching to binary mode on the client-side.

Comment: I tried it and got the same behavior. Hm... This is super perplexing.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem if you download the file from another computer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to any other computer on the network.  I have requested that it be tested, though.

Comment: I was given access to test on another server within the network and the same behavior occurred - which leads me to believe that it's a network issue.

Comment: “Only when we connect to an FTP server that uses the standard control port of 21 does the transfer have problems.” Sounds like firewall issues.

Comment: If there's an issue with the firewall, have you tried SFTP, SCP or any other FTP alternatives?

Comment: I've attempted SFTP and it does work correctly - I don't have the option to switch to it for my process, unfortunately, since I don't have any control over the source of my data.  I gotta get FTP workin.  :P

Comment: Antivirus software often intercepts FTP sessions to scan files and will prevent a transfer from completing if it thinks there is something wrong. Miss-configured or broken such software might end up doing it to all files.

Comment: FTP Considered Harmful.

Comment: @TomO'Connor I'm sorry, Tom, could you expound on that a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response:   426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content

There is *definitely* a Firewall in between which intercepts the FTP Traffic. Microsoft FTP to my knowledge does NOT support scanning content.

To be clear: This is more of a ***central firewall*** thing than a ***windows firewall*** thing.

Also, the theory of the *non-standard-port*-working supports this. (Central FW only seems to inspect traffice to port 21)

Take this up with your network admins.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  As per my final edit on my question, we rebuilt the settings on the firewall and it fixed the issue.

But further, I think you were correct.  Their firewall is a WatchGuard Firebox, though I'm not sure which model, that scans FTP content for viruses.  My biggest guess is that there was a rule or something that was corrupt, or a misconfigured option.

Comment: Ah, did not realize that edit that you already fixed it :) sorry.

Comment: It's okay!  You were totally right anyway, and it'll be easier for someone else to see and read your answer if they come across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well based on the "426 Data connection closed. Error scanning content" message you are getting. This looks like it could be a network firewall scanning for viruses.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1105801.aspx?Troubleshooting+FTP+426+Errors+Connection+closed+transfer+aborted+